# Save variables between View Controllers using a segue

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, segue

I use Swift and Xcode 6.4 and I would like to pass a variable from one View Controller to another using a Segue.
When you press the button, the variable duration should give the value to the ViewController2. In the ViewController2 I want to use this variable again.

Main.storyboard button identifier called Test1

How can I do that? Can you help me with my code? Whats wrong?

Thanks

Code ViewController1:

import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

@IBAction func ButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var duration = 1.0
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Test1", sender: duration)
}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier = "Test1") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2
        let duration = sender as Double
        secondViewController.duration = duration
    }
}
```

}

Code ViewController2:

import UIKit

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

```
var duration:Double?

var result = duration + 2.0
println(\(result))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
```

}

Comment: make your VC1 var duration global instead of local. As is, when button pressed, VC1 makes duration = 1.0, then sends message to segue } but then duration is lost...PrepareForSegue{ begins and new duration is created which = nil, then passed.

Comment: did this resolve the problem?

Comment: I have a problem there: if (segue.identifier = "Test1") { Cannot assign to identifier in segue (segue.identifier is underlined red)

Comment: you need ==...... `if segue.identifier == "Test1" {

Comment: I have done that, but now there is another error in the lower line: let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2

Comment: you can't just say there's an error! and leave it at that!....ummm maybe you should describe the error....

Answer (score 0):

```
var duration = Double()  // now "duration" is global

@IBAction func ButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    duration = 1.0
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Test1", sender: duration)
    // VVV Any new variable created in this scope will be deallocated 
}   // HERE

//Then this scope starts...
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "Test1") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2
       // delete this... duration = sender as Double
        secondViewController.duration = duration
    }
}
```

Comment: `sender` is meant to be the object that initiated the segue, generally `self`.  It's not meant to be a parameter you want to pass to destination view controller.

Comment: yes sorry missed that in the copy/paste of his code